# program not working on arduino leonardo

Tags: arduino

I have a program that works on an uno with serial output but does not work on a leonardo with the only changes being the keyboard press and release. I am using a coin mech and it is outputting a pulse when a coin is added. It did however trigger a load of times when the cable came loose from the pin the signal was being sent from

```
    const int coinInt = 0; 
//Attach coinInt to Interrupt Pin 0 (Digital Pin 2). Pin 3 = Interrpt Pin 1.

volatile float coinsValue = 0.00;
//Set the coinsValue to a Volatile float
//Volatile as this variable changes any time the Interrupt is triggered
int coinsChange = 0;                  
//A Coin has been inserted flag

void setup()
{
  attachInterrupt(coinInt, coinInserted, RISING);   
//If coinInt goes HIGH (a Pulse), call the coinInserted function
//An attachInterrupt will always trigger, even if your using delays
}

void coinInserted()    
//The function that is called every time it recieves a pulse
{
  coinsValue = coinsValue + 0.05;  
//As we set the Pulse to represent 5p or 5c we add this to the coinsValue
  coinsChange = 1;                           
//Flag that there has been a coin inserted
}

void loop()
{
  if(coinsChange == 1)          
//Check if a coin has been Inserted
  {
    coinsChange = 0;              
//unflag that a coin has been inserted
    Keyboard.press('+');
    delay(100);
   Keyboard.releaseAll();    
//Print the Value of coins inserted
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the problem, but I see that coinsChanged is set in the interrupt function and tested in loop(), but is not declared volatile.

I'd change

```
int coinsChange = 0;
```

to

```
volatile int coinsChange = 0;
```